# Distinct values with multiple Sum aggregations on reverse relation

Tags: django, django-orm

According to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations) combining multiple aggregations with annotate() will yield the wrong results because joins are used instead of subqueries. They furthermore note, that `Count` has a distinct parameter that may help.

Is there something similiar to `Sum`? I end up with wrong results in this stripped down example. The resulting `amount` values are too high for most projects.

```
qs = Client.filter('project__date__year=2017').annotate(
    isum=Sum('project__intoffer__amount', distinct=True),
    esum=Sum('project__extoffer__amount', distinct=True)
)
```

The `distinct=True` parameters don't make any difference.

Simplified `models.py`:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=50)

class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=100)
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client', verbose_name='Client')
    date = models.DateField('Date', blank=True, null=True)

class IntOffer(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, verbose_name='Project')
    amount = models.DecimalField('Amount', max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)

class ExtOffer(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, verbose_name='Project')
    amount = models.DecimalField('Amount', max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use django [Subquery expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions). In your case your query look like this:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, OuterRef, Subquery

qs = Client.filter('project__date__year=2017').annotate(
    isum=Subquery(Project.objects.filter(client=OuterRef('pk')).values('client_id').annotate(sum=Sum('intoffer__amount')).values('sum')[:1]),
    esum=Subquery(Project.objects.filter(client=OuterRef('pk')).values('client_id').annotate(sum=Sum('extoffer__amount')).values('sum')[:1])
)
```

Note that it can be slow on large tables, in this case probably better to use RawSQL.

Comment: Thanks, Subquery expressions look like a good alternative to stay in the ORM. For some reason, i still get unexpected results using them, have to look deeper into it. `cart=` in your filter is supposed to be `client=`, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, I used Subquery in my project and use it as example, so forgot to change this filter. I didn't test it try to look at generated sql (`str(qs.query)`) it can be useful, maybe ORM generate something wrong.